# How is it possible to call a locally defined function from its symbol?

Tags: common-lisp

According to the CLHS, `FUNCALL` argument is a [*function designator*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm), which can be a symbol denoting a function defined in the global environment.  I am looking for a way to do this locally, like in this example:

```
(defun test ()
  (let ((name 'local-function))
    (flet ((local-function ()
             'hello))
      (funcall name))))
```

I am looking for a way to get the function definition from the local environment.  Is it possible with Common Lisp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just trying to call a local function using `funcall`, note that a function designator can also be the function object, and you *can* get that by using the `(function name) == #'name` notation.  I.e., you can do:

```
(defun test ()
  (flet ((local-function ()
           'hello))
    (funcall #'local-function)))
```

You can *return* this value, too, and so let the local function “escape” outside.  E.g., you could implement a counter:

```
(defun make-counter (init)
  (flet ((counter ()
           (incf init)))
    #'counter))

; This case is simple, and could have been:
;
; (defun make-counter (init) 
;   (lambda ()
;     (incf init)))
```

```
(let ((counter (make-counter 3)))
  (list (funcall counter)
        (funcall counter)
        (funcall counter)))
;=> (4 5 6)
```

As [uselpa pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20036715/1281433) though, you won't be able to get the function object via a symbol, much in the same way that there's no association at runtime between the symbol named `"X"` and the lexical variable `x` in

```
(let ((x 'foo))
  x)
```

The lexical variables don't have any association at run time with the symbols that named them in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_designator), no. It doesn't work with `eval` either. I suppose that at run-time there is no trace left of the local function's name.

Also, my understanding is that if the function designator is a symbol, then `symbol-function` is used, which is [not defined](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_1.htm) for local functions.